# Custom lighting components in mobile app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, custom

I've developed some custom components which are working great on Lightning desktop mode.

I'm also able to create a custom tab within inside my custom components. **Sadly** that is not what I'm looking for, that is because my **custom** component is tightly related to the **custom/standard** object in which the components appear in desktop mode. (Meaning that they MUST be on the same page and work together)

What I'm trying to figure out, is that if it is possible to integrate my custom component inside a standard tab, and if it is not possible, how do I include my standard object within the custom tab and custom components?

I'll leave here a simple mockup, each custom components need to be shown related to the other custom component present on the page, and both of them need to be on the same page as the standard object.

[image: mockup]

Comment: Did you take a look at Quick Actions with lightning component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @kurunve was saying, yes I only needed the quick actions for my requirements.

Thanks!